# How do I get a div to move with window resize without pushing other divs out of the way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've spent a long time trying to get this working.

I have a section called "RightExtra" and a div inside it called "RightExtraContent". I'm trying to make it so that these two divs can move freely when the window is resized up to a certain point, without affecting the position of any other divs.

Here is a visual explanation of what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwP32.png

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c21nzs13/1/

I've tried a bunch of different code combinations and still no success.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  background: #1e1e1e;
  /*Back Colors 1*/
}
body {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  /*background:url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/4657039731.jpg');*/
}
a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.nofancy a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*These nofancies don't work*/

.nofancy a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*These nofancies don't work*/

#heady {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  /*Back Colors 2*/
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*background-color:#1e1e1e;                       Back Colors 3*/
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
#RightExtra {
  background-color: none;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#RightExtraContent {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #343434;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
}
#followfoot {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: none;
  text-align: center;
  /*display:none;*/
}
#mag {
  background-color: #739FE0;
  border-color: #739FE0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#feety {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  //100px background-color:darkslateblue;

  /*Back Colors 4*/
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  //Changing this to relative makes followfoot disappear when you scroll long enough.

}
.UpCenter {
  /*background-color:#1e1e1e;                                        Back Colors 5*/
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 90px;
}
.SignUp {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
/* clearfix */

/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf {
  * zoom: 1;
}
ul.navbar {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #739FE0;
  width: 100px;
  /*Widthchanger1*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 33px;
}
ul.navbar li a.ActiveListItem {
  color: white;
  !important;
  background-color: #222 !important;
  padding: 7.5px 0px !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  margin-left: 0px;
  /*Widthchanger2, got the activeitem centered with list text this way*/
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 100px;
  /*kinda messes with width of text*/
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
ul.navbar li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  /*Changes width of actual list*/
}
ul.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}
ul.navbar li a:hover,
ul.navbar li:hover > a {
  /*background:black; */
  background: #739FE0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /*font-weight:600;*/
  /*border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-style:solid;*/
  /*border-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px; */
}
ul.navbar li ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*Controls space from listdropdown to listchooser*/
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* min-width: 200px; */
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
/*Lister*/

form {} .lister input {
  width: 235px;
  /*width of todo input box*/
  height: 33px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #739FE0;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}
.lister input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #739FE0;
  /*ccc*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px #739FE0;
}
.lister ul {
  /*list-style: square inside;*/
  padding: 10px 0px 55px 0px;
  /* padding for outside area of list*/
  /* This is what's visible when not in use Used to be 10*/
  /*height:50px;*/
  /*background: #0f705d;           DarkerOutsideColor*/
  background: none;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  font-family: "Tahoma";
}
.active {
  text-align: center;
}
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
.lister li {
  font-size: 14px;
  /*font size of list items*/
  /*font-weight: 600;*/
  color: #181818;
  /*Font Color d5faf3*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*This makes the items side-by-side and not columns*/
  padding: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*SEPARATE*/
  /* float:left; Interferes with text-align of Active*/
}
.lister li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #343434;
  /*LighterInside Color,Odd*/
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
  color: #ccc;
  /*opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);*/
}
.lister li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #343434;
  /*LighterInside Color,Even*/
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
  color: #ccc;
}
.lister li > a {
  /*float: right;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*transition: all .2s ease-in-out;*/
  /*position:relative;*/
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.lister li > a:hover {
  /*font-size: 105%;*/
  /*color: #c0392b;*/
  color: #000000;
}
.lister li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 379px;
}
/*Clearable*/

.clearable {
  /*background: #fff; */
  /*background:url(../images/splusgreen.png); */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: right 5px center;
  /* -15*/
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
.clearable.x {
  /*background-position: right 5px center;*/
}
.clearable.onX {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="heady">
  <div style="width:1000px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <div style="text-align: left;padding:25px 0px;display:inline-block;float:left;font-size:18px;"><b><a href="index.html">Calories</a></b>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;padding:25px 00px;display:inline-block;float:right;">
      <!--<a href="profile.html">Home</a> | --> <a href="index.html">Sign In</a> | <a href="index.html">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="RightExtra">
  <div id="RightExtraContent">Yes hello....!</div>
</section>
<section id="wrapper">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="UpCenter">
    <div style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;">
      <ul class="navbar cf">
        <li> <a href="#" class="ActiveListItem">Category</a>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="lister" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" class="clearable" placeholder="Add your meals here..." autocomplete="off">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="mag" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
      <img src="images/magCircy.png" width="33px" height="33px" onClick="changeHeight(this,event);"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="followfoot"></section>
```

Comment: **stop** using inline `style=""` while using (as you should) an external stylesheet. It lead you exactly where you are: in trouble :)

Comment: Good point, that may be hindering me more than I realize.

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce your Question's titile in your own demo. Nothing pushes anything *out of the way*. It's just **overlapping** :)

Comment: Also as a side-note, I can see you expect a *responsive* website, but at the same time you're setting elements (like i.e: `#wrapper`) to a fixed width... Which makes your question even more incomprehensible :\

Comment: I mean, you should use **media queries** and widths defined in **responsive units** (like `%` or `vh/vw`) to achieve what you want (if I've understood your question well)

Comment: Oops, I mean that in the time that I was messing with the code one of the problems I had was that it would push elements. I've since altered the code numerous times and now it's at a state of simply overlapping. I don't know how to get it to do what I want, which is explained some here : http://i.imgur.com/A3qBGsj.png Basically just trying to get the div to freely move but only up to a certain point, and to never move other divs out of the way

Comment: So setting up the entire page to work using %s rather than fixed pixel widths would be the way to do this?

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't understand *what DIV*? What about the form with inputs? How's it supposed to be aligned and responsive? What elements should be exactly responsive and which ones should have a fixed width? I mean, sorry for being a pain, but by throwing hundreds of lines of CSS is not helpful for one to help...

Comment: Sherri I would personally recommend you take a good look at Bootstrap, there's  small learning curve but they've built a responsive framework that can do what you want. You'll learn a lot along the way.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I personally don't like BS (cause it's a total overkill and when going into design details slows down totally the progress) but, sincere and helpful comment

Comment: You're not being a pain, haha, I appreciate the help. To answer your question, I'm referring to the section "RightExtra" and the div it contains which is "RightExtraContent". That is what I am trying to get to be in a certain place and to be capable of moving upon window resize up to a certain point without affecting the positions of any other divs/sections. The other pieces on the page are in their correct positions and move as desired upon window resize.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're not wrong. I'm more recommending it because she wants to build something that may be a bit above her head and if she starts at bootstrap she'll learn a lot. But I guess my comment is off base.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu that's why we have the comment section *to comment*! :) Sherry... ok, but what should happen once that minimal size is reached? I mean what you expect from the form element (the one with inputs) and other elements to behave like?

Comment: when the minimal size is reached, all elements would stop moving upon resize and the user would just see an essentially static page. So basically, the whole website would be resizable only up to a certain point. It is working that way except for with the section and div in question. If you're asking about the functionality of the elements on the page, I purposely didn't include the JS because I'm having problems with just the CSS/HTML

Comment: @Sherri so basically, the form should be centered at all times and the right DIV should adjust in width?

Comment: If that's how the solution is reached, yes. I'm not sure what the correct approach is. With the other elements it was a matter of getting the right position settings and such. This one is more confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, I increased the width of the wrapper and moved the new div into it.